# Django page not found when passing date

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm building django app with django rest framework (DRF). I have model with DateField type and I want to query based on date in yyyy-mm-dd format for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/dataharian/2021-08-09/. I used the path converter as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)
with some adjustments so the URL able to accepts yyyy-mm-dd format. Here is the DataHarian model, DataHarian view, the converter, and the URL.py file

DataHarian model:

```
class DataHarian(models.Model):
    tanggal = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    kumulatif = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sembuh = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dalam_perawatan = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    meninggal = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tanggal)
```

DataHarian view:

```
class DataHarianDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = DataHarian.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataHarianSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

Converter :
from datetime import datetime

```
class TanggalConverter:
    regex = '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value
```

URL.py

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from datetime import datetime
from . import views, converters

register_converter(converters.TanggalConverter, 'yyyy-mm-dd')

urlpatterns = [path('dataharian/<yyyy-mm-dd:tanggal>', views.DataHarianDetail.as_view()),]
```

*Tanggal is date in Indonesian

If my explanation isn't good enough, please give a feedback
Thank you for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, APIViews do lookups based on the field `pk`.  To override this, DataHarianDetail needs `lookup_field` set:

```py
class DataHarianDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'tanggal'
    queryset = DataHarian.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataHarianSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

However, you're going to run into problems if multiple records can share the same date.  The API will throw an error when there are multiple matches.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I designed one record only hold single date (tanggal). Your solution worked for my case. So next time I need to specify the lookup_field in order to complete the URL request?. Thank you very much for the response